# Unwanted window appears

Tags: pyqt

I've written a short class to create a new window, with a tab menu, and a canvas on one of them. Every time I launch the app two windows show up. One of them is the wanted one, the other one is an empty one. I'm new to OOP in python, I guess I miss something in my class.

```
class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tab1 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QtGui.QWidget()


        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)


        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.tab1.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Database")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Current")
        self.tabs.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was here:

```
if __name__=='__main__':    
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = GUI.Window()

    #main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The main.show() cause the problem.